# What are the "no-content style elements"?

Tags: html, css

[This cool article](http://css-tricks.com/15135-simple-styles-for-horizontal-rules/) briefly discusses no-content style elements. Particularities include that they don't have closing brackets, and `:before:` and `:after` cannot be used on them. Examples include `hr` and `br`.

Where can I find an exhaustive list of such elements?

Comment: What's wrong with the HTML standard?  That's the exhaustive list of all HTML tags.

Comment: Why shouldn't `:before` and `:after` work on them? They mean "before the element" and "after the element", there is no connection to the (eventual) content of the element.

Comment: @Viruzzo: No, `:before` and `:after` mean before/after the element's *content*, not *the element*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These elements are commonly known as [empty elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.1), i.e. they can't have any content, which is why `:before` and `:after` can't be used on them:

> Some HTML element types have no content. For example, the line break element `BR` has no content; its only role is to terminate a line of text. Such *empty* elements never have end tags. The document type definition and the text of the specification indicate whether an element type is empty (has no content) or, if it can have content, what is considered legal content.

You can find a whole list of them in [this table](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/elements.html).

In the HTML5 drafts, they are known as [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements). Here's the list:

> **Void elements**
>   `area`, `base`, `br`, `col`, `command`, `embed`, `hr`, `img`, `input`, `keygen`, `link`, `meta`, `param`, `source`, `track`, `wbr`